# How does WSO2 APIM handle 40x http error codes returned by endpoint?

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-esb

I'm working with WSO2 APIM 3.1.0 and some of my endpoints are getting constantly in SUSPENDED state.

The endpoint was built to return http code 400, 403, 404 as part of its business logic.

In the **Advanced Configurations** for a given endpoint, we might set the **Error Code** to move the endpoint into suspension or timeout state.

The error codes below are available for selection:

```
101000  Receiver input/output error sending
101001  Receiver input/output error receiving
101500  Sender input/output error sending
101501  Sender input/output error receiving
101503  Connection failed
101504  Connection timed out (no input was detected on this connection over the maximum period of inactivity)
101505  Connection closed
101506  NHTTP protocol violation
101507  Connection canceled
101508  Request to establish new connection timed out
101509  Send abort
101510  Response processing failed
```

Http codes, such as 400/403/404, returned by the endpoint are mapped to some of those WSO2 error codes ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, If you set suspension code, it will be internally mapped with the response code.

Comment: what is the error codes to response code (HTTP status code) mapping?

Answer (score 0):

No, If your backend sends 400/403/404 error codes, it means the backend is working and responding. The error codes are applicable if the backend is not functioning.

The error codes we provide in the endpoint configuration are our internal error codes, which we receive when the backend server is not functioning. It is not possible to directly map backend status codes with the internal codes mentioned in the list.